# How Adding slash into rewrite rules href link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slash

i am using the rewrite rules in htaccess but i am getting error on site,
while adding a / (slash) into the link

My Example Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^categories/(.*)$ ?act=directory&category=$1 [L]
```

actually i want to call this link from the category listing where the href link is

```
categories/category-name
```

now if i call this link like this

```
categories-category-name
```

then it works fine, but if i add the slash then the site looks as it doesnt have the css :(
only unstyled text i can see.

Thanks In Advance
Please Advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a slash in your css path

```
href="/css/your_style_name.css"
```

This will work